# Footer for my webpage is VERY wrong but I don't understand what is conflicting

Tags: html, css, footer

I don't understand what is happening to the footer on my webpage at all. Mainly with the weird line of black opacity which shouldn't be there. I don't know why its happening. Here's a link to the [page](http://gff.mx/gdes220/students/07/P2finaldraft/index.html). I also made a codepen for the html and css [here](http://codepen.io/jenngga/pen/NxqjPb). I'm sorry I'm new and just trying to get to the bottom of this, so any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
            <footer>


                <img id="imgfoot" src="img/aperture_labs_bot.png" alt="aperture laboratories footer line" ><!-- width= "2400" height= "68" -->

            <div class="center1"><h3>Aperture science, we do what we must because we can.</h3>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="center1"><h4> Questions or Comments? Contact us!</h4>
            </div>
                <br>


                <a href="tel:425-889-9642">
            <div id="left">
             <div class="overlay1">
            <span class="text">Phone: 425-889-9642</span> </div></div></a>

            <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/Ln7Pshy1htM2">
            <div id="center">
             <div class="overlay2">
            <span class="text">P.O. Box 1688 Bellevue, WA 98009</span> </div></div></a>


            <a href="mailto:Aperture.Science.gmail.com?subject=The-Cake-is-not-a-lie!">
            <div id="right">
             <div class="overlay1">
            <span class="text">Aperture.Science.gmail.com</span> </div></div></a>



                <br>
                <div class="center1"><h4> Do you want to apply to be a test subject? Do you also like free cake and $60? Apply now!  <a div id="redacted" href="WebForm.html"><span style="background-color: #000000">REDACTED.</span></div></h4></div>

            </h4>   

    </footer>
```

Comment: The codepen and the live site behave differently. I don't even see the black line in codepen.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your file called layout.css and delete lines 75 and 76

<strike>background: url(../img/aperture_labs_bot.png) no-repeat fixed; 
          background-image: url(../img/aperture_labs_bot.png);</strike>

```
    footer {
       DELETE:  background: url(../img/aperture_labs_bot.png) no-repeat fixed; 
       DELETE: background-image: url(../img/aperture_labs_bot.png); 
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: contain;
     background-position: center;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-size: cover;
     max-width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: Wow I feel really stupid... Thank you so much! By the way... would you have a moment to spare to assist me with positioning and why the second box imge is not showing up? I really appreciate it so much. I will also update the site with the change if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have some invalid html markup. Try and make sure the html opening and closing tags are all correct, use a html validator tool or IDE to help.

W3 is a great tool to validate markup
https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fgff.mx%2Fgdes220%2Fstudents%2F07%2FP2finaldraft%2Findex.html will guide you on what some of the validation errors are.

For example you have the following opening tags

div > h4 > a > span

then the corresponding closing tags

span < div < h4 < div < h4

---

So look at cleaning up this html block

```html
<br>
<div class="center1">
  <h4> Do you want to apply to be a test subject? Do you also like free cake and $60? Apply now!  <a div id="redacted" href="WebForm.html"><span style="background-color: #000000">REDACTED.</span></div></h4>
</div>

</h4>
<br>
```

With something similar to...

```html
<div class="center1">
  <h4>Do you want to apply to be a test subject? Do you also like free cake and $60? Apply now!  <a div id="redacted" href="WebForm.html"><span style="background-color: #000000">REDACTED.</span></a></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: I know my code is really bad currently, I'm still in the demo stage. Thank you for catching that, I thought I had fixed it earlier but clearly I was wrong! I've been sick with strep and trying to finish this up.